# Code-First EF Core with Serilog to SQLite

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-core-2.0, serilog

Application related architecture can be described as:

- isolates logging from the application by using abstraction (e.g. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging);
- uses use Code-First approach to create a database;
- an application may record some information to log before calling the EnsureCreated from DatabaseFacade.

As a result:

- Configuring Serilog is part of the IHost creation process when the application starts;
- Serilog creates a database in front of EF Core on first run;
- EF Core won't create a database because it was created by Serilog;

Questions:

- Can I instruct EF Core to update the database schema without creating migration steps for the entire database?
- Is it possible to delay/prohibit Serilog from creating a database (e.g. allow only to update existing database)?
- Are there any other options for achieving a similar result?

Answer (score 0):

Configure serilog

```
IDictionary<string, ColumnWriterBase> columnOptions = new Dictionary<string, ColumnWriterBase>
{
   { "message",             new RenderedMessageColumnWriter(NpgsqlDbType.Text) },
   { "message_template",    new MessageTemplateColumnWriter(NpgsqlDbType.Text) },
   { "level",               new LevelColumnWriter(true, NpgsqlDbType.Varchar) },
   { "raise_date",          new TimestampColumnWriter(NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTz) },
   { "exception",           new ExceptionColumnWriter(NpgsqlDbType.Text) },
   { "properties",          new LogEventSerializedColumnWriter(NpgsqlDbType.Jsonb) },
   { "props_test",          new PropertiesColumnWriter(NpgsqlDbType.Jsonb) },
   { "machine_name",        new SinglePropertyColumnWriter("MachineName",                       PropertyWriteMethod.ToString, NpgsqlDbType.Text, "l") },
};

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Destructure.UsingAttributes()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.PostgreSQL(
        connectionString: connectionStringHere,
        tableName: "Logs",
        columnOptions: columnOptions,
        needAutoCreateTable: false,
        schemaName: "public",
        useCopy: true,
        queueLimit: 3000,
        batchSizeLimit: 40,
        period: new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10),
        formatProvider: null)
    .CreateLogger();
```

then you can create C# class mapping those database fields

```
[Keyless]
[Table("Logs")]
public class ActivityLogs
{
    [Column("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [Column("message_template")]
    public string MessageTemplate { get; set; }

    [Column("level")]
    public string Level { get; set; }

    [Column("raise_date")]
    public DateTime RaiseDate { get; set; }

    [Column("exception")]
    public string Exception { get; set; }

    [Column("properties", TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public string Properties { get; set; }

    [Column("props_test", TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public string PropsTest { get; set; }
}
```

if you want to add more columns then you need to modify your C# model class and columnOptions as well.

---

*PS: Here I have tried to explain how to use Code-First approach to create a database for serilog. Let me know if you have any other question*